# Finding $p$-value of a test, no population mean given.

Tags: probability

How do I find  the $p$-value of this sample ?
$$10, -1,6,7,-5,-5,2,-3,8,9,-2$$
I do not know the population mean, only that it came from a normal distribution.

My problem finding $Z$ value first then I can proceed.

Comment: Sorry, without a hypothesized mean, there can be no p-value, since there is no hypothesis test stated.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that these were differences in final exam marks and the practice exam. I am thinking to use zero as population mean, for claims that final scores were higher.

Comment: It's really critical that you be able to specify hypotheses before you ever acquire (or look at) sample data. Failing to do so makes your question nonsensical/unanswerable -- and in practice, would count as research fraud.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to show that the mean difference in test scores increased from the practice to the final exam, then the hypothesis should be structured as:  $$H_0 : \mu_\delta = 0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \mu_\delta > 0,$$ where $\mu_\delta$ is the true mean difference in scores, as measured by the final score minus the practice score for each examinee.

Suppose we have $n$ examinees, and their practice scores are $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.  Their final scores are $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$.  So for exam-taker $i$, the difference in scores is $$\delta_i = y_i - x_i$$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.  Then you would use a simple one-sample $t$-test, with the statistic $$T = \frac{\bar \delta}{s/\sqrt{n}},$$ where $\bar \delta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i$ is the sample mean difference, and $s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (\delta_i - \bar \delta)^2}$ is the sample standard deviation of differences.  Then $T$ is Student's $t$-distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, and the $p$-value for the one-sided test is the probability $$\Pr[t_{n-1} > T],$$ where $T$ is the value of the statistic you calculated from the data, and $t_{n-1}$ is a Student's $t$ random variable with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  This is actually a **paired $t$-test** on the matched pairs of practice and final test scores $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$.

Your first step is to calculate $\bar \delta$ and $s$.  Then calculate the test statistic $T$.  Once you show me what these values are, then compare the result to a table of Student's $t$ values to get the $p$-value, or I can tell you what the resulting $p$-value will be.

Comment: It seems like it would be notationally simpler in this exercise to just treat the given differences as the $x$ data points.

Comment: Oh yes i got Sx= 5.08125 and sample mean = 2.3636 , p = 0.103 , please confirm thanks

Comment: @ste Yes, those are correct.